# How can I use the gmp package to utilise a loop for an extremely large number?

Tags: r, loops, gmp, largenumber

I have developed a loop that calculates the largest prime factor of a given number.

```
for(i in (p-1):(1)){
if ((p%%i)==0){
p<-append(p,i)
}
}

n<-c()
for (i in p){
if (sum(i/1:i==i%/%1:i)==2){
n=c(n,i)
}
}

max<-max(n)
```

This works for the numbers that r can handle. However, when I try this for the large number 600851475143 I recieve the error:

```
long vectors not supported yet
```

I understand this is a problem with r not being able to handle large numbers. I have tried getting around this by using the gmp package:

```
install.packages("gmp")
library(gmp)
```

And using as.bigz with my number:

```
 p<-as.bigz(600851475143)
```

But this returns the error:

```
Error in (p - 1):(1) : unimplemented type 'raw' in 'asReal'
In addition: Warning message:
In (p - 1):(1) : numerical expression has 20 elements: only the first used
```

How would I use the gmp package (or a similar package) to perform the loop I have made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.package("gmp")
library(gmp)
factorize(600851475143)
```